# Android Studio Gradle"File google-services.json missing module root. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it."

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I keep getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   > File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta5'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta5'

}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
jcenter()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.computing.lincolnopenday"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Read the docs and add the generated file.

Comment: see here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file

Comment: Did you create the google-services.json file via Google's API website ?

Answer (score -1):

You can't use

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta5'

Because the newest one is

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html

Also, [here](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/2.0.0-beta5/view) is suggestion is to add

> compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta5'

For building with gradle.